# C# mysql "serialization" library

Tags: c#, mysql

I have wrote a library that allows me to easy execute insert and select queries for MySql. It allows you use attributes similar to XmlIgnore, XmlProperty...
However I feel that I have reinvented the wheel. Is there already something that allows me to do this using MySQL ? Or am I completely doing this wrong ?

```
public class ClientDto
{
    [DatabaseField("name")]
    public string Name { get; }

    [DatabaseField("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [DatabaseIgnore]
    public string HasAddress => !Address.IsNullOrEmpty();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connector = new DatabaseTableConnector<ClientDto>("client");

        var clientDto = new ClientDto()
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            Address = "123 fake street"
        };

        connector.Insert(clientDto);

        var anotherClientDto = connector.Query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client.name = 'Alice'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you have reinvented the wheel, you've created an ORM. Try looking at Entity Framework for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a little like a weak JPA(Java). Maybe it has something from the C# Entity Framework (C#), but I didn't use this before.

I personnaly don't understand, why you write something like this. There are more professional frameworks out there for sure.
 Pros: You don't need to write them, they are very powerfull and well documented. 
Just search for ORM, you should find somewhat like this for nearly every language.